# How to open crash reports from PLCrashReporter into XCode to get the line number of crash

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, plcrashreporter

I am able to get the crash reports from PLCrashReporter after the app runs again.

But even after symbolicating the crash report. It still not giving line number of crash.

Though its providing Class name and Function name in confiscated way like this:

> 4   ProjectName                              0x00000001022fab3c $s6Notary19LoginViewControllerC27forgotPasswordButtonClickedyyypF + 140

In the above LoginViewController is the class name and forgotPasswordButtonClicked is the function name.

But xcode crash to be sent to apple for improvements. The crash report in that is dito copy of it. But in non-confiscated way. Its more readable. Pasting that here too:

> 0x1022fab3c LoginViewController.forgotPasswordButtonClicked(_:)+140(LoginViewController.swift:106)

In the above line number is also added and is more readable.

So i guess there must be some way we can extract the more readable report from the PLCrashReport.

Attaching 2 screenshots of both for more clarity. Drew red rectangle around it.

This one is from PLCrashReporter Logs

[image]

And this one is from XCode crash report to send to apple.

[image]

**Whats Needed is:** As a developer we will get the logs (As in image1 above) our app sends to server. Please guide me if there is a way so we can use those crashLogs to be open in xcode (As in image2 above) so we can have better readability which helps us to reproduce the issue.